# Failed to load module 'AudioKit'

Tags: audiokit

Downloaded new Audiokit framework from audiokit web-page AudioKit.xcframework
created project in xCode, added this framework in framework settings.
then when i write "import AudioKit", prompt help showing me AudioKit, so system sees the Audiokit Module,
but then, when I typed it, it says: "Failed to load module 'AudioKit'"

what can be a problem?
xCode ver 11.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the cause of the problem. I did however just use the Swift Package Manager to install AudioKit v5 which worked a treat. Have you tried it?

There is a section on the AudioKit GitHub front page about using SPM - https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit.

I'm pretty sure that older versions are also available this way.